# Store json file in MS SQL

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server

I have a JSON file, how to store a JSON file in MS SQL? And read the file data after storing it into Database?

I'm using a python script to interact with SQL Server.

Note: I don't want to store key-value pairs as an individual records in DB, I want to store the whole file in DB using python.

Comment: *"Starting SQL Server 2016 and beyond you can declare a datatype in your DB as JSON"* This isn't true, @apomene . Unlike XML, JSON doesn't have a data type in SQL Server. [Data types (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). SQL Server 2016+ can parse JSON, however, there is no specific JSON data type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific data type for JSON in SQL Server, unlike say XML which has the `xml` data type.

If you are, however, storing JSON data in SQL Server then you will want to use an `nvarchar(MAX)`. If you are on SQL Server 2016+ I also recommend adding a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to the column to ensure that the JSON is valid, as otherwise parsing it (in SQL) will be impossible. You can check if a value is valid JSON using [`ISJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). For example, if you were adding the column to an existing table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD YourJSON nvarchar(MAX) NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT chk_YourTable_ValidJSON CHECK (ISJSON(YourJSON) = 1 OR YourJSON IS NULL);
```

Answer (score -2):

<s>SQL server has a JSON data type for this.</s> This is wrong.

If your version doesn’t, you can just store it as a string with VARCHAR <s>or TEXT</s>.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) reckons `NVARCHAR(max)` is the answer for documents greater than 8KB, for documents under that you can use `NVARCHAR(4000)` which apparently has better performance.

Comment: *"SQL server has a JSON data type for this."* SQL Server doesn't have a JSON data type. It has been able to *parse* JSON since SQL Server 2016, however, none have a specific data type for JSON. Also, `text` has been deprecated for 15 years; long past time to stop recommending it use.

Comment: I want to store the whole JSON file, don't want to store JSON data as a record in DB.

Comment: @ATULSHARMA a JSON is just the JSON text stored in a file, anything that can go in a JSON file can go in a record in a DB. If you don't want to store it in a record where do you want to store it?